# Use C# to save photos to directory that user has no access to

Tags: c#, security, filesystems

I'm working on a WPF application right now in C#, and I need to be able to save some images.  These images need to be saved into a directory that the user that's currently logged in doesn't have access to without some administrative privileges (essentially, to control the security on what images are being saved to that directory).

How can I set up such security permissions?  Is there some directory that I can add subdirectories to with these images inside?

Normally, I would try to post some code in example to what I have.  I'm not entirely sure where to begin with this problem, though.

Comment: You would need to do something that runs as a different user; otherwise, if the user's program can do it, so could they. The easiest route to go is probably a local service that your program connects to; the service only accepting connections from local system users, and saving the file(s) on their behalf.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: How would you suggest that I go about doing that?  I don't have a lot of experience writing services in Windows.

Comment: @ashays take a look at the [ServerBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx) class. If you are running Visual Studio you have a project type that is Windows Service that you can use. If not, start with the `OnStart` and `OnStop` functions.

Comment: If I am the user of your application and it runs in my box, why should the application decide what images can be stored in one of my directory?

Comment: @Ramesh: The application is being written so that guests can access the application and save images using this application, but not tamper with the image files that the application creates (or the folder where it saves them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew already told in his comment you should really best start with a service. This will run under another account (normally System, but you can change this within the control panel). To start with this a service is in the first step nothing more than any other normal process. So to get a connection between the user application and the service you can use [any inter-process communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx) as you like.

The only difference between a normal application and a service is that the service will be started and managed through the service manager and thous needs to derive from [`ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx). Also maybe this [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) might help you to start.

Answer (score 0):

Default context for all non-user programs is `system` which it available to you via `service programming` and you are not familiar with it. A hack would be logging into another account (i.e administrator) and run the program in that context which is not possible on all windows versions and I believe doesn't worth the resources it cost and also is a security risk.

Another solution would be `encrypt` your application data and store it somewhere.